# URL encoding of en-dash

Tags: path-aliases

I had a link:

```
www.example.com/issues/issue-week-2012–2013/poem1
```

But it is encoded as:

```
www.example.com/issues/issue-week-2012%25E2%2580%25932013/poem1
```

This is an URL alias, the en-dash (between "2012" and "2013") is encoded as `%25E2%2580%2593`, which shows a 404 error. But when I removed the "25" after each `%` in the URL manually it works.

Please tell me about the issue?

Comment: Why do you need an en-dash? Can't you just use a dash and avoid all this?

Comment: @Clive actually that url alias is created by the issue name typed by the client. And i don`t know from where he got this bloody en-dash..:-)

Comment: And i think % is again got encoded to %25 thats why %E2%80%93(encoded string for en-dash) is being encoded to %25E2%2580%2593

Comment: Where do you see encoded URL which is causing problem ? I mean how is URL alias getting generated ? Using Path Auto ?

Comment: @AnilSagar yes..and i can`t do anything in that. because it is creating as generated by the user`s input.

Comment: It's strange .. Since using path auto i am unable to replicate above encoding issue.. Path Auto does convert and work with all special characters..

Comment: @AnilSagar So what are you at? Share you point.I am very needy in this situation

Comment: so, What i would like to know is more details so that we can replicate issue and try figure out what's wrong.. With out more details where we can not replicate the issue it's highly impossible to solve your issue.... What exactly user input is when created node content ? What is your pattern setting in path auto ? If you cannot give more details this question will be either closed as "Off Topic - This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution for the bug.

Actually the edit page (`node/*/edit`) is a secure page (HTTPS) and view page is not (HTTP). So while clicking any URL in the edit page, it will encode that URL in to HTTPS and then to HTTP (if the redirected page is not a secure page).

Here the URL gets encoded twice:

First:

```
https://example.com/issues/poems-week-2012%E2%80%932013/storyname
```

And then:

```
http://example.com/issues/poems-week-2012%25E2%2580%25932013/storyname
```

This bug can be fixed if the edit page is a normal page (not a secure page). And it seems that this will not make any security breach for the system.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a solution using a RewriteRule in .htaccess.

Imagine I have the url `/some-page`

Now if I go to `/someTESTpage`

and I put this in .htacess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)TEST(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Then it redirects to:

```
/some‒test
```

Problems still to solve:

1) In the redirect URL that is an en-dash so is still the wrong url. Not sure how to get it to insert the correct character.

2) When I put a percentage sign in the string to be replace the whole thing stops working. Not sure how to escape a percentage sign in a RewriteRule.